# Can the Twenty Eleven theme have a Main Sidbar at all?

Tags: sidebar, theme-twenty-eleven

After pulling my hair trying to find out [why my Main Sidebar disappeared](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41029/main-sidebar-dispappeared-what-could-possibly-cause-this), I performed as a last act of desperation a [complete wipeout of the database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/643/12658) and the entire wordpress directory, then I restored them from the earliest backup of my totally fresh install of WordPress, which includes **only the home page and the original sample page** and **no plugins!**.

That didn't help displaying the Main Sidebar.

But when I switch to `Twenty Ten`, the Main Sidebar, with the calendar in it, is there!

This is insane, as I am now beginning to doubt my memory that I ever saw the Main Sidebar on `Twenty Eleven`.

Can the Twenty Eleven theme have a Main Sidebar at all?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a *user-support* question, that would be better-asked at the [Twenty Eleven support forum at wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/tags/twentyeleven?forum_id=5).

Comment: @Chip Bennett Thanks for your comment. What does this mean? I am new to WordPress and to the WordPress community in particular, so I am unsure which forum is for what. If a "user-support question" doesn't fit this SE board, what kind of questions are better asked here? +1 for now.

Comment: Please refer to the [Scope as defined in the FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). Generally, WPSE is intended for questions related to WordPress *development and administration*. User-support questions are better served at the [official wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the Twenty Eleven theme have a Main Sidebar at all?

Twenty Eleven Theme does display a sidebar on the homepage, but not on the single posts and individual pages as you can see from the [demo of Twenty Eleven](http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/).

> If so, what am I doing wrong?

What's your website URL?

Comment: Thank you! I am beginning to see the light at the end of the tunnel. The server on which this WordPress instance is installed is internal on a LAN (behind NAT & firewall) so it isn't accessible from the web. In the meanwhile I managed to find [many hints](http://goo.gl/9X2iC) about this newly introduced "feature" in Twenty Eleven. I will continue to research for [a workaround](http://surminski.eu/2011/07/06/add-sidebar-to-single-post-in-the-wordpress-3-2-twentyeleven-theme/). +1 for now.

Comment: Finding more information on this, it looks like [this feature](http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/a-page-with-a-sidebar/) has a good purpose: [Fitting mobile phones](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/sidebar-gone-on-frontpage-when-using-mobile). I wonder what that "Selecting the **custom Sidebar Template** for your page" means. Where do I find it?

Comment: When we edit any page, on the right side, on the "Page Attributes" box, there is an option to choose the sidebar template.